# How to open a page against each richfaces menuitem on the same webpage

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am new to Java, looking for answer(s) to the following question. I am building a website using JSF, in which i am using a richfaces menubar (panelMenuGroup and panelMenuItem). I want to display a new page in front of the menubar against each item of the menu (i.e. when i click a menuitem i open a new page in front of the menu bar). Any solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

u can create a `h:commandLink` and on action call the respective bean's method which returns the desired page

```
pulic String welcome(){
  ..
  return "\welcome.xhtml";
}
```

Comment: but this will open an new page(closing the page where action was called), i want to keep that page opened but open this new page in front of the menubar. It is like clicking on an item and displaying the corresponding page in front of the menubar.

Comment: u can use `rich:menu` and `rich:menuItem` and use ajax support to achieve this